# function decreaseSizeImage() on rollover on several images

Tags: javascript

I can successfully do this with one image in a document:

```
var glbInc, glbDec;


function decreaseSizeImage() // will get back to its normal default size
{
if(glbInc != null) {clearTimeout(glbInc); glbInc = null;};
if (document.getElementById("idImage").height > 111)
{
document.getElementById("idImage").height -= 1;
document.getElementById("idImage").width -= 1;
glbDec = setTimeout("decreaseSizeImage()", 6);
};
}

function increaseSizeImage()
{
if(glbDec != null) {clearTimeout(glbDec); glbDec = null;};
if (document.getElementById("idImage").height < 222)
{
document.getElementById("idImage").height += 1;
document.getElementById("idImage").width += 1;
glbInc = setTimeout("increaseSizeImage()", 6);
};
}
```

But when I try it with more than one image, only one of the images will expand, regardless which image is rolled over. I have no idea how to set up so that it will work smoothly for

Comment: What is the markup you are using for more than 1 image? If you are using the same id, that would be a problem. If not, you need to alter your code to work with an array. FYI, if you can use jQuery, that would make this easier, and more cross browser compatible.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I'd lay this out for multiple images.  Passing the image element via 'this' avoids having to use any IDs.  Not tested!

```
function decreaseSizeImage(img) { // will get back to its normal default size 
    if (img.height > 111) {
        img.height -= 1;
        img.width -= 1;
        setTimeout(function() {
            decreaseSizeImage(img);
        }, 6);
    }
}

function increaseSizeImage(img) {
    if (img.height < 222) {
        img.height += 1;
        img.width += 1;
        setTimeout(function () {
            increaseSizeImage(img);
        }, 6);
    }
}

...

<img src='myimage.png' onmouseover='decreaseSizeImage(this);' onmouseout='increaseSizeImage(this);'>
<img src='myimage2.png' onmouseover='decreaseSizeImage(this);' onmouseout='increaseSizeImage(this);'>
```

Comment: James, thanks for your modifications.  It now works fine for multiple images, though the speed has decreased. I actually meant for the image to increase on rollover (pasted the wrong piece of code in the subject!), but it was very simple to reverse the code.  Great solution!

Comment: Greg, thank you too.  Time will tell if there are cross browser issues ... As I'm a newbie, getting it to work on my browser is very exciting.  I will do some testing, though.  Thanks again.